# Pandas read_csv with multilined header xls file

Tags: python, pandas

How can I read the header of the following xls file using pandas?

[image: xls file]

All column headers such as DATE, BENCHMARK NAME are on line 3 but the percentile values "1ST (PERCENT)" are on line 4.

When I try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(xls_url, skiprows=[0,1,7], header=3) # or header=[3,4]
```

I get the following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 13, saw 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `read_csv` on an .xls file. If you save the file as a .csv you can see what the .csv header looks like and it should be straightforward.

Otherwise use `read_excel` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html)). It should be along the lines of:

```
pd.read_excel(xls_url, skiprows=3)
```